Indesign: Inserting pages numbers without using masterpages?
I have a 200 pages document with several masterpages.
How can I insert pagenumbers without going through masterpages? I already used the placeholder process, but the only thing that shows up numbered is the pagesoverview, not the pages itself, apart from page n.1.

I'm trying to think of a reason why one would not use Master pages and I'm coming up blank....

Ok, found out myself by try and error:
Solution: Insert the placeholder in each of the masterpages. It will translate in the document according to the place it holds in the pages overview. No matter which masterpage has been applied.
Hope this helps someone else
Greetings

Another time you could make a master which you base all your other masters on. Whatever you add on that first master will also be on the other masters.
